# Create ID column based on last update date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I will create table, where `ID` is `PRIMARY KEY`. I will insert columns: `Name` and `ABSValue` and `LastUpdateDate = GETDATE()`.

The problem is that I want to generate `PctChange` values which are equal for example to: *(val1_5 - val1_1) / val1_prev * 100* (the number after the underscore is the ID value).

My question is how to get the previous value, so I can make the calculation which will go to `PctChg`? Is it possible to do this when inserting?

| ID | Name | ABSValue | PctChg | LastUpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val 1 | 13 | 0% | 2021/01/08 |
| 2 | val 2 | 45 | 0% | 2021/01/08 |
| 3 | val 3 | 3 | 0% | 2021/01/09 |
| 4 | val 2 | 50 | 11% | 2021/01/09 |
| 5 | val 1 | 10 | -23% | 2021/01/13 |

Comment: I don't follow the calculation.  What is `val1_5`?

Comment: `val 1` in row 5, or the last added value if you look at the LastUpdateDate

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes a unique key (Name, LastUpdateDate) constraint exists on the table.  The values to be inserted are declared as variables.  The declared variables are then selected in a CTE and OUTER APPLY is used to located the original (according to LastUpdateDate) row for each Name.  The percent change is calculated as DECIMAL(14, 2).  Something like this.

```
/* values to insert */
declare
  @Name               varchar(20)='val1',
  @ABSValue           int=10,
  @LastUpdateDate     date=getdate();

/* use the select statement to insert into table */
;with
all_cte([Name], ABSValue, LastUpdateDate) as (
    select 'val1', 14, cast(dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) as date)
    union all
    select 'val1', 10, cast(dateadd(day, -3, getdate()) as date)
    union all
    select 'val3', 10, cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
    union all
    select 'val1', 10, cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)),
ins_cte([Name], ABSValue, LastUpdateDate) as (
    select @Name, @ABSValue, @LastUpdateDate)
select i.*, oa.*, 
       cast(case when oa.ABSValue is null then 0
                else (i.ABSValue-oa.ABSValue)/(oa.ABSValue*1.0)*100 end as decimal(14, 2)) calc_pct_change
from ins_cte i
     outer apply (select top(1) ABSValue
                  from all_cte a
                  where i.[Name]=a.[Name]
                        and i.LastUpdateDate>a.LastUpdateDate
                  order by LastUpdateDate) oa;
```

Output

```
Name    ABSValue    LastUpdateDate  ABSValue    calc_pct_change
val1    10          2021-01-13      14          -28.57
```